# Is there any direct method in perl to find out the total number cells in the MS Word table?

Tags: perl, ms-word, ole

I want to find the total number of cells present in the following table[image]

Product of number of cells and number of column

```
my $lastrow = $table->Rows->{Count};
my $lastcol = $table->Columns->{Count};
my $cells = $lastrow * $lastcol ;
```

would not give me the exact number of cells present in the table.  Is there any other to find the number of cells present in the table??

Comment: Please say what module you are using for your sample code.

Comment: @Borodin I am using "Win32::OLE".

Answer (score -1):

If you have a `docx` file then it is standard XML and could be processed using one of Perl's many XML modules.

But if you have a `doc` file then there is no way to do this that I know ofthat I know of.

Comment: Oh the ever-wearysome anonymouse downvoter. I would love to know what is wrong with my answer but I am sure you're going to keep it a secret.

Comment: This “answer” isn't useful/very low quality. Having an XML file doesn't help us unless we are familiar with the structure, with the way that cells are encoded. This is why higher-level bindings exist (e.g. via OLE).